# how to deserialize xml to list in RestSharp?

Tags: c#, xml, xmlserializer, restsharp

My XML:

```
<result>
    <document version="2.1.0">
        <response type="currency">
            <currency>
                <code>AMD</code>
                <price>85.1366</price>
            </currency>
        </response>
        <response type="currency">
            <currency>
                <code>AUD</code>
                <price>31.1207</price>
            </currency>
        </response>
    </document>
</result>
```

My Class:

```
public class CurrencyData
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Price { get; set; }
}
```

My deserializer calling:

```
RestClient.ExecuteAsync<List<CurrencyData>>...
```

If i renamed class `CurrencyData` to `Currency` then all will been done right. But I want to keep this class name.

Comment: The `DeserializeAs` attribute works correctly on a single item, however it doesn't work on a collection. The problem is that the deserializer check for the `DeserializeAs` attribute within the alternate workflow that is used for collections. I was able to get it working with literally 2-3 lines of code in the `HandleListDerivative` method (I took the source of the XmlDeserializer` class on Github and registered it as a custom deserializer with my change).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I think I got it,

You can try `RestClient.ExecuteAsync<Result>()`

```
[XmlRoot("result")]
public class Result
{
    [XmlElement("document")]
    public Document Document { get; set; }
}

public class Document 
{
    [XmlElement("response")]
    public Response[] Responses { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("version")]
    public string Version { get; set; }
}

public class Response
{
    [XmlElement("currency")]
    public CurrencyData Currency { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
}

public class CurrencyData
{
    [XmlElement("code")]
    public string Code { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("price")]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

I had to add a few `XmlElement` attribute to override the casing without having to name classes and properties in lowercase. but you can drop them if you can change the xml to match the casing

Comment: Ah yes, aliasing. My point below was that the names have to match and the RestSharp guide gives you a rundown on how it does the lookups.

Answer (score 1):

Answer of [kay.one](https://stackoverflow.com/users/98970/kay-one) is perfect! It works with a any remarks:

```
public List<Response> Responses { get; set; }
```

works

```
public Response[] Responses { get; set; }
```

don`t works

And

```
[XmlElement("AnyValue")]
```

it is from System.Xml.Serialization namespace and don`t work. 
Feel free to just delete them. 
In this example annotation attributes and properties has same names and serializer understands.
But right annotation attributes are from RestSharp.Deserializers namespace

```
    [DeserializeAs(Name="AnyXmlValue")]
    public string AnyModelValue { get; set; }
```

[How to manage deserialization of RestSharp](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/wiki/Deserialization)

Answer (score 0):

Then change the xml tag to CurrencyData. Here is the documentation about the xml deserializer: https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/wiki/Deserialization

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why Kay.one's answer is accepted, it doesn't answer the question.

Per my comment, the default RestSharp deserializer doesn't check for the `DeserializeAs` attribute when deserializing a list. I'm not sure if that's intentional or a mistake as the author doesn't seem to be very available.

Anyways it's a simple fix.

```
    private object HandleListDerivative(object x, XElement root, string propName, Type type)
    {
        Type t;

        if (type.IsGenericType)
        {
            t = type.GetGenericArguments()[0];
        }
        else
        {
            t = type.BaseType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
        }

        var list = (IList)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
        var elements = root.Descendants(t.Name.AsNamespaced(Namespace));

        var name = t.Name;

        //add the following
        var attribute = t.GetAttribute<DeserializeAsAttribute>();
        if (attribute != null)
            name = attribute.Name;
```

Comment: where do you put this?  hoping we don't have to modify the RestSharp library because we're using it in Xamarin...

Comment: I'm not sure if it's an oversight or not.  I've been away from things for a bit so I'll take a look into it now that I'm back.